# How do I use Meteor.js browser Javascript Console?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Launching new Meteor.js project. In client.js I put

```
var hi = "widget";

    if (Meteor.isClient()){
    ...
    }
```

In my Browser's Console, and I type:

```
>> hi
ReferenceError: hi is not defined
>> this.hi
undefined
```

Comment: http://meteor.com/blog/2013/04/04/meteor-060-brand-new-distribution-system-app-packages-npm-integration see "other changes"

Answer (score 1):

It is probably locally scoped.

Try:

```
var global = Function("return this")();
global.hi = "widget";
```

Comment: is this available in the Javascript Global Object DOM somewhere?

Comment: @JackChi it becomes a global variable, just type `hi` in console after it has run

Comment: hmm where is the "hi" part?

Comment: @JackChi I am not sure what you are asking, I am getting a reference to the global object, then assigning `hi` as a property of the global object. Therefore `hi` becomes a global variable, and you can type `hi` in your console and hopefully not get a `ReferenceError`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this has changed just recently in version 0.6 and seems to be just a bug. If you remove var at the declaration of hi, the scope of the variable will change and it will become accessible via JS console. Still, it's a temporary situation, which will be likely be fixed in the future releases.

Comment: It's not a bug and it won't be "fixed". It was a design change. Declaring variables with "var" will make them local to the file. They're global otherwise.